# Remove element with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have the following code below.

It is built in a pretty crappy system, so I cant change the HTML. What I need to do is to use "display: none" on the first and the second "tr" in tbody. How can I accomplish this through CSS?

I have tried the following without working:

```
.left-bar table tbody tr:nth-child(1),
.left-bar table tbody tr:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

and

```
.left-bar table tbody:nth-child(1),
.left-bar table tbody:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

The code

```
<td class="left-bar">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div class="page_title additional" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">Ange betalningsadress</div>


                    Ange er fakturaadress för den specifika ordern tack.
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="white_dot.gif" width="1" height="10" border="0"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</td>
```

Comment: Try to use `display: none !important;` which overrides other styles.

Comment: What @Doodlebunch said. Would also be helpful if you provide us with any CSS styling the table might already have if that doesn't work.

Comment: This one is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4f7wuLn/2/)

Comment: This works fine http://jsfiddle.net/1257w8cj/ ... share the markup of the entire table of td left-bar

Comment: an alternative would be to use `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: Thanks guys, worked like a charm! (Danko, give me more than 6 min. Thanks for the answer)

Comment: :P if your answer is now solved please delete this ...